# sublime text indentation fix?

Tags: python-3.x, sublimetext3

I always get an indentation error in python 3 in sublime text. Could anyone help me fix this error.

```
def encrypt(number):
    r = []
    for letter in s:
        l = ord(letter)
        r.append(l)
    print(r)
```

Answer (score 1):

This happens because you are mixing spaces and tabs in your code. Go to editor settings, there will be an option called `use spaces for tabs`. For the code, and easy option is search for `tabs, replace it with four spaces. If you copy this code back and call the function, it will work as SO has no tabs, only spaces for code :

```
def encrypt(number):
    r = []
    for letter in s:
        l = ord(letter)
        r.append(l)
    print(r)
```

Answer (score 1):

Select all your text, then click at the bottom right on `Tab Size: x` and then on `Convert Indentation to Tabs`.

The problem is surely that your indentation is sometimes made of *spaces* and sometimes made of *tabs*. However, you have to chose either one or the other. That problem often come when copy-paste code from outside.

Was this helpful?

Thank you

Comment: By far the most used and recommended way of indenting in Python is to use 4 spaces. Some editors cannot adjust the tab width, while other editor settings may interfere with display as well. The most Pythonic way of indenting is 4 spaces, as it always displays exactly as intended. The only place tab characters should appear in a `.py` file is in formatting strings.

Comment: So click on `Convert Indentation to Spaces`, just a matter of convention. Thank you for your remark by the way, I didn't know that `Spaces` were more used than `Tabs`.